# Can't call method with PUT or POST

Tags: web-services, http, asp.net-web-api, put

I can request an API method via http://requestmaker.com/ using GET, but when I use POST or PUT it returns...

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Here is the method...

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/sales")]
public object Put([FromBody] Sale sale)
{
   sale.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

   paymentRepository.Insert(sale);
   paymentRepository.Save();

   return Ok(new { id = sale.SaleId });
}
```

Any ideas?

Request headers are...

> POST /admin/api/sales HTTP/1.1 Host: hello.com Accept: */*
>   Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 17

Request data...

```
TourId=3&UserId=1
```

Comment: Cant have more than one FromBody parameter attribute

Comment: That's what I want. It works with GET using FromUri. I suppose I have to create a single model to bind from body.

Comment: No, I'm not. Wouldn't that stop GET from working too?

Comment: FromUri builds complex model from uri, FromBody extracts simple types from complex model in body https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: update you question with Request headers

Comment: try to send a request data `{
   "TourId":"3",
   "UserId":"1"
}` and content type `application/json` and make the `[RequestBody]`  of type Sale

Comment: No change, I'm afraid with JSON formatted data and change in content type.

Comment: @ajdrausal JSON formatted data and change in content type was actually required for binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh silly me, it was looking for an anti-forgery token. I thought I'd commented the filter out, but I'd done it for MVC and not Web Api. Oops.

I also needed to set the content type to `application/json` and set the data as `{ "TourId":"3", "UserId":"1" }` in order for model binding to work.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how your Controller is routing the requests. You seem to have defined something like this

Defaults To GET:

```cs
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MethodName(){ 
  return this.Ok()
}
```

or

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MethodName(){ 
  return this.Ok()
}
```

There should be some attributes that you can define above the function:

For POST:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MethodNamePost(){ 
  return this.Ok()
}
```

For PUT:

```cs
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MethodNamePut(){ 
  return this.Ok()
}
```

Like Win said:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/sales")]
public object Put([FromBody] Sale sale)
{
    sale.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    paymentRepository.Insert(sale);
    paymentRepository.Save();

    return new { id = sale.SaleId };
}
```

I would change the return to `this.Ok(new {id = sale.SaleId});` though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Request headers are wrong it should be like

```
{
"UserId":"1",
"TourID":"3",
}
```

REASON:application/json